# Мексиканская волна

Tags: php, массивы

как сделать волну такого образца:

> ```
> ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
> ```

Код есть, но выдает немного не верный результат:

```
function wave($people){
    $array = [];
    $i=0;
        while( $i < strlen($people)){
            
            $people[$i] = strtoupper($people[$i]);
            $array[] = $people; 
            $i++;
            
        }
    var_dump($array);
}  
echo wave('hello');
```

Comment: а как выглядит "немного неверный результат"?

Comment: array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "HEllo"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "HELlo"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "HELLo"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "HELLO"
}

Comment: ну вроде бы тут понятно, что происходит, не? Если в слове Hello капитализировать букву Е и результа записать **вместо** предыдущего значние, то получится HEllo. И так далее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим так

```
function wave($people){
$array = [];
$i=0;
    while( $i < strlen($people)){
        $temp = $people;
        $temp[$i] = strtoupper($people[$i]);
        $array[] = $temp; 
        $i++;
    }
var_dump($array);

}
echo wave('hello');
```

Не нужно затирать каждый раз предыдущее значение.

Comment: нет, явно не то. мне нужно чтобы в следующем слове. предыдущая буква была которая была в верхнем регистре  переходила в нижний. как бы создавался эффект "волны". а вашем решении у меня просто буквы верхнего регистра упаковываются в массивы. у меня на входе строка, а на выходе 1 массив из 5 элементов должен бытью вот так -->  ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]

Comment: подправил, попробуйте

Comment: многобайтовые строки так работать не будут.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wave($sting){
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($sting); ++$i) {
        if ($sting[$i] == ' ') continue;
        $result[] = substr_replace($sting, strtoupper($sting[$i]), $i, 1);
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(wave('hello world'));
```